# completion(.dismiss) в Notification Content Extension

Tags: ios, swift, apple, уведомления

Здравствуйте. При работе с уведомлениями нужно, что б по нажатию на кнопку уведомление скрывалось. Обрабатываю нажатие клавиш вот так:

```
        func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {
    switch response.actionIdentifier{
    case "correctAnswer":
        label?.text = "Correct"
    case "nonCorrectAnswer1", "nonCorrectAnswer2":
        label?.text = "Non Correct"
    default:
        break
    }
    completion(.dismiss)
}
```

Проблема в том, что уведомление никуда не пропадает, а остается висеть. Если заменить на completion(.dismissAndForwardAction) то контроль передается в основное приложение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверьте екшены , должно быть что-то такое, была похожа проблема в options, решилась передачей пустого масива

```
let correct = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "correctAnswer", title: "correct ", options: [])
```